# `\autoref` seems broken in latest revtex4-2

Tags: hyperref, miktex, revtex, autoref

`\autoref` can no longer generate hyperlinked cross-reference in the latest revtex4-2 document class.

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
% !TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass[superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
    \title{The current document class: \textbf{revtex4-2}}
%   \title{The current document class: \textbf{article}}
    \maketitle
    The equation is below
    
    \begin{align}\label{eq:Hamiltonian}
        f(x) &= x^2
    \end{align}
    
    The model \autoref{eq:Hamiltonian} provides us the opportunity to study.
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Probably I missed any proper options for the latest revtex4-2? Or is it just a bug?

Comment: revtex overwrites the \label definition and so breaks links. The author has been notified and I have also a pending new version for hyperref to work around the issue but it will take a few days until this on ctan. As work around use what is suggested in https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/284

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a lot for this! It works.

Comment: For what it is worth, I came to this site because I just downloaded and installed the latest package updates, and now a working document created with the svmono class from Springer is no longer playing nicely with hyperref. I am experiencing very similar symptoms. The prevailing error is: ! Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete. which I was not getting before the package updates installed through the MikTeX console. (I realize that this is not an answer. I do not have the reputation to comment. Nevertheless, this is a serious issue which I hope somehow gets brought to the attenti